# How to embed a TextEditor in a Composite in an Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I created a multi-page editor (`MultiPageEditorPart`) with 2 pages:

1. A Text Editor, class that extends `org.eclipse.ui.editors.text.TextEditor`.
2. A page in which I need to display a split view, on the left the Text Editor from page 1 and at the right side the visual representation of the source.

The problem is adding the Text Editor at the left side of the split view on page 2, I tried adding it to a `Composite`, like this:

```
Composite leftSide = new Composite(parent, SWT.NONE);
leftSide.setLayout(new FillLayout(SWT.HORIZONTAL));

MyTextEditor sourceView = new MyTextEditor (leftSide); // This class extends TextEditor
```

and then adding the 2 pages to the multi-page editor:

```
int index = addPage(sourceView); // This page contains only the Text Editor
setPageText(index, "Source View");

int index = addPage(splitView); // This page needs to contain the Text Editor and other composite
setPageText(index, "Split View");
```

The first page (Source View) loads the Text Editor just fine, syntax highlight and all other features are working as expected but the left side of the split view, which is supposed to load the same Text Editor looks like a blank space, is there a way to embed the Text Editor in the composite? or is there any other way to achieve that?

Comment: You will need to call the life cycle methods of the `IEditorPart` yourself - particularly the `IEditorPart.init` method using a suitable editor site. This is what `MultiPageEditorPart` does when you add the editor to that. I suggest you look at the source of `MultiPageEditorPart`.

Comment: Thanks! I tried to pass the sourceView to the splitView and call `sourceView.init(sourceView.getEditorSite(), sourceView.getEditorInput());` and `sourceView.createPartControl(parent);` which displays the Text Editor in the composite but I noticed some strange behavior, like the cursor is not displayed in the Text Editor and the content assist doesn't work in the split view, probably because both classes share the editorSite and editorInput, I looked at the source code of the class MultiPageEditorPart, specifically in the addPage method and that is what they do

Comment: You have to create a specialized editor site, you can't reuse the normal one. The `addPage(int index, IEditorPart editor, IEditorInput input)` method of `MultiPageEditorPage` uses a `MultiPageEditorSite`